# Rotate text not displaying properly on right side using CSS

Tags: html, css, rotation

I have to rotate the text on the right side but rotate text is not displaying properly.Now it is displaying in the center I need on right side out of the container.Also, I have to display the full text from the top. Check out the snippet in full view.

I need output like this

[image]

```css
 

h2{
margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
    .parent_div {
     margin-top: 100px;
     }
    .v_fluid_title{
     position: relative;
     right: 0;

    }

    .v_fluid_title h2{
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     font-size: 55px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
        -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari 3-8 */
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="parent_div">
 <div class="v_fluid_title">
   <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</h2>
    </div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="text_content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotations in CSS are rather tedious. There are three main things to keep in mind:

1. The Rotation itself

This isn't hard at all. You can do that using `transform: rotate(90deg);` like you did. You have that right

2. The `transform-origin`

This is what will solve your posted problem (but do read on). This tells the browser where to rotate it. The default is the middle of the object. In your case you either want this to be the top right or move the div to another position. Note that you often have to use `transform: translate(x, y);` with this.

Example:

```css
.right {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
}

.rotated {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(100%, 0);
  transform-origin: 100% 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="right rotated">
  Hello world!
</div>
```

3. The element width

This is the hardest part. Relative units always refer to the unrotated element. That means that `width: 100%` on an `rotate(90deg)`-element will set its **height** to 100% **width** of its parent.

Since you want it to spread the full height of the viewport (I assume), you are lucky in that you can easily solve this using the `vh`-unit, but note that this isn't supported in older browsers! If you need support for those then you probably have to use js.

```css
.right {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  width: 100vh;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.rotated {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(100%, 0);
  transform-origin: 100% 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="right rotated">
  Hello world!
</div>
```

Comment: I used 3rd one and I change the from position: fixed; to position: absolute; because I need in one line.and I don't need to be fixed. It's working perfectly

Comment: Sure, this was just supposed to be an example not the solution. Glad I could help you

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like this?

```css
.content,
.rotated-title {
  display: inline-block
}

.content {
  width: 70%
}

.rotated-title {
  width: 29%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 45px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-100%) rotate(90deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%) rotate(90deg);
  /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: translateY(-100%) rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
    eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div class="rotated-title">
    I AM TITLE2
  </div>
</div>
```